# Powershell - Start-Process ArgumentList accepts only single variable with spaces

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to start my script from Explorer. I've found the solution and it works if script doesn't have any parameters.

```
$file = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory() + "\Trees.ps1"
Start-Process powershell -verb runas -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File `"$($file)`""
```

However, if I add additionall parameters just like the first it ceases to work. Ie. this code throws "The string is missing the terminator: '." error.

```
$file = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory() + "\Trees.ps1"
$Context = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()
Start-Process powershell -verb runas -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -Context '"$($Context)'" -File `"$($file)`""
```

I'm using this way of expecting variable:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string]$Context,
```

What can I do to pass more then one variable with spaces in ArgumentList?
I suspect that I should pass arguments for file content in other way than when just passing file name, but couldn't find solution.

Comment: Those are single quotes around $context, not backticks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the back ticks issue that Theo noted, `-context` should follow `-file`.

```
-File
    Runs the specified script in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the
    functions and variables that the script creates are available in the
    current session. Enter the script file path and any parameters.
    File must be the last parameter in the command, because all characters
    typed after the File parameter name are interpreted
    as the script file path followed by the script parameters.
```

So your command line would be

```
Start-Process powershell -verb runas -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File `"$($file)`" -Context $($Context)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using an external process call, you will need to use inside double quotes instead of single quotes. You can escape double quotes simply by adding another double quote (`""`).

```
Start-Process powershell -verb runas -ArgumentList "-ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted -File ""$file"" -Context ""$Context"""
```